# Why is my <ul> not centered or floating to the left?

Tags: html, css

Why is my list not floating to the left, and why is it showing extra white space to the RHS?

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Someone</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=La+Belle+Aurore' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homeStyle.css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="homeButtons">
        <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Me</a></li>
        <li>My Work</li>
        <li>My hobbies</li>
        <li>Contact Me</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
    </ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="homeScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the corresponding CSS:

```
body {
   /*background-image: url("http://good-wallpapers.com/pictures/1737/ubuntu_prettified_background.png");*/
    /*position: fixed;*/
    height: 9em;
    width: 16em;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.homeButtons {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 16em;

}

ul.homeButtons li {
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: inherit;

    list-style: none;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 1px;


    float: left;
    clear: none;
    color: white;
    background: #1e90ff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    /*border-radius: 2px;*/
    opacity: 0.5;

    -webkit-transition: all .4s;
}

ul.homeButtons li:hover {
    font-size: 2.7em;

    box-shadow:
        0 0 0 20px #1e90ff,
        0 0 20px 24px #d3d3d3;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul.homeButtons li a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra white space to the right of your `ul` is coming from the default padding that most browsers put on lists.  You can do set `ul { padding: 0; }` to get rid of it.

Consider removing all of the `position: relative;` and `width` specifications - they don't seem necessary in this example

FYI, there are many reset stylesheets out there which do a good job of removing the browser's default styling.

Comment: Thank you so much! :D You are just plain awesome! :D